# Repeatedly Press Key for Chrome Tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to run a script on a tab in chrome that presses the shift key every 3 seconds. Even when I switch tabs, it should keep clicking the shift key.

Code like `document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].click()`
doesn't work for some reason. I think its because the body is getting clicked, rather than the page itself

Comment: click is for mouse click events, not keypress events.

Comment: @James I know, i can easily just replace the .click() with a shift command. I just want to know how to do "send" a keypress to the browser